# Insert the value of a variable in a String

Tags: javascript, string

Is this code bit wrong,

```
var num = 3;
var str = "The number is " + num!";
```

How to fixed this,

Comment: how about `"The number is " + num + "!"` ?

Answer (score 0):

hi try the following:

```
var num = 3;
var str = "The number is " + num + "!";
```